# Counting the occurrences of an object in an array of objects based on a key

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of objects as follows :

```
let people = [
              { name: "Emily", age: 15 }, { name: "Emma", age: 16 }, 
              { name: "Stacy", age: 18 }, { name: "Emily", age: 15 },
              { name: "Jennifer", age: 12 }  
             ];
```

I need to return the result containing the age as the key and frequency as it's corresponding value as follows :

```
{ 15 : 2, 16 : 1, 18 : 1, 12 : 1 }
```

I wish I could implement this using both forEach() and reduce().

Comment: Why both forEach and reduce??

Comment: So what's the problem? Loop through the array. If the current age exists in the result object, add 1 to its value. Otherwise add a property whose value is 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const people = [ { name: "Emily", age: 15 }, { name: "Emma", age: 16 }, { name: "Stacy", age: 18 }, { name: "Emily", age: 15 }, { name: "Jennifer", age: 12 } ];

const ageCount = people.reduce((map, { age }) => ({
  ...map,
  [age]: (map[age] || 0) + 1
}), {});

console.log(ageCount);
```

Comment: Don't do their homework for them.